# Why is `loop` not a keyword? What is the use case for `loop` without a block?

Tags: ruby, loops, keyword

I was wondering why `loop` is a `Kernel` method rather than a keyword like `while` and `until`. There are cases where I want to do unconditional loop, but since `loop`, being a method, is slower than `while true`, I chose to do the latter when performance is important. But writing `true` here looks ugly, and is not Rubish; `loop` looks better. Here is a dilemma.

My guess is that it is because there is a usage of `loop` that does not take a block and returns an enumerator. But to me, it looks that an unconditional loop can easily be created on the spot, and does not make sense to create such an instance of `Enumerator` and later use it. I cannot think of a use case.

1. Is my guess regarding my wonder correct? If not, why is `loop` a method rather than a keyword?
2. What is the use case for an enumerator created by `loop` without a block?

Answer (score 1):

Only Ruby's developers can answer your first question, but your guess seems reasonable. As to your second question, sure there are use cases. The whole point of Enumerables is that you can pass them around, which, as you know, you can't do with a `while` or `for` structure.

As a trivial example, here's a Fibonacci sequence method that takes an Enumerable as an argument:

```
def fib(enum)
  a, b = nil, nil

  enum.each do
    a, b = b || 0, a ? a + b : 1
    puts a
  end
  puts "DONE"
end
```

Now suppose you want to print out the first seven Fibonacci numbers. You can use any Enumerable that yields seven times, like the one returned by `7.times`:

```
fib 7.times
# => 0
#    1
#    1
#    2
#    3
#    5
#    8
#    DONE
```

But what if you want to print out Fibonacci numbers forever? Well, just pass it the Enumerable returned by `loop`:

```
fib loop
# => 0
#    1
#    ...
#    (Never stops)
```

Like I said, this is a silly example that clearly is a terrible way to generate Fibonacci numbers, but hopefully it helps you understand that there are times—albeit perhaps rarely—when it's useful to have an Enumerable that never ends, and why `loop` is a nice convenience for those cases.

Comment: It kind of make sense.